# Android: Problem with the camera opening in webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-camera2

After a few days struggling with opening camera within webview I decided to ask the question here.

So,
I have a webview in my app which open a web page where is a camera. To forestall the questions, I do not have access to the website code.

I work on the android sdk 30 and Pixel 3 api 30. I tried it to open also on old android SDKs (23 - 24) or on the newest android 12. Tried to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage` with target sdk version 29.

When i try to open the given website in the chrome on my emulator it works correctly.

I think it can be problem with camera permissions but i have no idea how to check it. Calling `requestPermissions` for the camera also didn't help me.

And I just keep getting this error all the time:

```
E/cr_VideoCapture: getCameraCharacteristics: 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: supportsCameraApi:2340: Unknown camera ID 0
        at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.throwAsPublicException(CameraManager.java:1001)
        at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(CameraManager.java:449)
        at ft0.i(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.aab-stable-489612734:1047)
        at org.chromium.media.VideoCaptureFactory.isLegacyOrDeprecatedDevice(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.aab-stable-489612734:1339)
        at org.chromium.media.VideoCaptureFactory.getFacingMode(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.aab-stable-489612734:93)
     Caused by: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: supportsCameraApi:2340: Unknown camera ID 0 (code 3)
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2387)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2357)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2340)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2282)
        at android.hardware.ICameraService$Stub$Proxy.supportsCameraApi(ICameraService.java:906)
        at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.supportsCameraApiLocked(CameraManager.java:1054)
        at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.supportsCamera2ApiLocked(CameraManager.java:1030)
        at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(CameraManager.java:422)
        at ft0.i(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.aab-stable-489612734:1047) 
        at org.chromium.media.VideoCaptureFactory.isLegacyOrDeprecatedDevice(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.aab-stable-489612734:1339) 
        at org.chromium.media.VideoCaptureFactory.getFacingMode(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.aab-stable-489612734:93)
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Then in your activity, You can check camera permission like below

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),Manifest.permission.CAMERA)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
```

}

Inside this condition you can use  android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE to get the list of camera intent from packagemanager